# `vboxmanage list hostonlyifs` creates host-only interfaces

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, ansible, virtual-network

If I run `vboxmanage list hostonlyifs` in my shell, I get the following output:

```
$ vboxmanage list hostonlyifs
Name:            vboxnet0
GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.56.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
MediumType:      Ethernet
Wireless:        No
Status:          Down
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0
```

This is what I expect: a single interface.

Now, if I run the exact same command in an Ansible playbook:

```
$ cat prepare_virtualbox.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: check if the host only interface already exists
      shell: vboxmanage list hostonlyifs
      register: hostonlyifs
      changed_when: false

$ ansible-playbook prepare_virtualbox.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************

TASK [check if the host only interface already exists] ***************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

something weird happens: additional host-only interfaces get created! If I run `vboxmanage list hostonlyifs` again, it lists three interfaces:

```
$ vboxmanage list hostonlyifs
Name:            vboxnet0
GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.56.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
MediumType:      Ethernet
Wireless:        No
Status:          Down
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0

Name:            vboxnet1
GUID:            786f6276-656e-4174-8000-0a0027000001
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.57.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:01
MediumType:      Ethernet
Wireless:        No
Status:          Down
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet1

Name:            vboxnet2
GUID:            786f6276-656e-4274-8000-0a0027000002
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.58.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:02
MediumType:      Ethernet
Wireless:        No
Status:          Down
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet2
```

If I run the playbook again, no new interfaces are created. But if I delete any of the three above (e.g. with `vboxmanage hostonlyif remove vboxnet1`), it gets recreated when I run the playbook again.

What could make this happen? How would I troubleshoot further?

Comment: Do you delete them through vboxmanage or externally?

Comment: @user1686 Sorry, should have specified. Through `vboxmanage hostonlyif remove <name>`. I'll add that to the question.